# Killing enemy player with an bullet class

Tags: javascript

So as the header says, im trying to make the enemies die by being hit by an laser, that is being shot by the player. 
It is probarly not a huge problem to fix, but I cant seem to find what the error is. Maybe one of you guys/girls on this site can find it ?

Thanks on the before hand

```
    //Bullet Collision 
    function NotP1BulletCollided(){
        if(LaserShot.x >= Player2.x && LaserShot.x <= Player2.x + Player2.width && Player2.y >= Player2.y && LaserShot.y <= Player2.y + Player2.height)
        { 
            alert("TEST");

        }
    }
    NotP1BulletCollided();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Bullet Collision 
function NotP1BulletCollided(){
    if(LaserShot.x >= Player2.x && LaserShot.x <= Player2.x + Player2.width && LaserShot.y >= Player2.y && LaserShot.y <= Player2.y + Player2.height)
    { 
        alert("TEST");

    }
}
NotP1BulletCollided();
```

This was the problem:

Player2.y >= Player2.y